# How can I download a DBI ODBC SQL Query to a file

Tags: dataframe, odbc, rstudio

I have the following code used for connecting to an ODBC driver and running a SQL query from an Oracle database:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),   
            Driver="Oracle in OraClient12Home1_32bit",
            DBQ="selfservice.coname.com:1523/PRD.WORLD",
            Schema="PRD",
            UID=rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database user"),
            WD=rstudioapi::askForPassword("Database password")
)

res <- dbSendQuery(con,
                   "select a.vsys_group_num,
                           a.vsys_plan_num,
                           a.vsys_subgroup_num, 
                           a.vsys_cs_code, 
                           a.tax_id, 
                           p.first_name,
                           p.last_name, 
                           a.acct_num, 
                           a.acct_status, 
                           a.cash_value_amt
                      from lhods.account_a a, 
                           lhods.participant_a p 
                     where a.vsys_group_num = '44936' 
                       and a.vsys_plan_num in ('003','001')
                       and a.tax_id = p.tax_id"
)

View(res) dbFetch(res)
```

**** dbFetch returns the first 500 rows of data from my query.  So I am seeing the correct results in the console ****

When I try to write the results to a file, no matter which functions I seem to try, I always get this error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) :    cannot coerce class ‘structure("Oracle", package = ".GlobalEnv")’ to a data.frame
```

How the freak can I get this into a file (txt, csv, excel, whatever)?  I know it's probably something dumb.  I've never tried to export data in R via ODBC.  I'm use to working with data from stat packages and excel, not from ODBC connections.  Please help, because I know it would be awesome to run this in R.

Comment: hi from your description and code, I don't see that you save your `dbFetch(res)`in a variable before you try exporting it?

Comment: I knew it had to be something where I could claim that I had a senior moment.  Trying to transfer multiple step sql/excel/access analysis into a single r script.  Had a few courses but never used on in a real world scenario.  I appreciate the help.  Works like a charm.